# Calculating Lipschitz constant of an unknown function from its data

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms, computational-mathematics, lipschitz-functions

I have an unknown four-dimensional function: $$u:X \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \to Y\, \text{where}\, X := [-5,5] \times [-5,5]\times [-5,5]\times[-5,5],\,Y= [-0.2,0.2],$$ and I have access to its values on $X$. Is there any methods/algorithms using which I can get an approximation of its Lipschitz constant?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you know $u$ is Lipschitz in the first place? There are functions on compact sets which are not Lipschitz.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger, I know it from a prior known result that $u(\cdot)$ is guaranteed to be Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Can you estimate the maximum norm of the derivative?